# java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message with FTP download

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm downloading a file from a FTP server, but I get a `NullPointerException`. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    ftpConnect("domain","username", "password", portnum);  

    try  
    {  
         String s = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();  
         File f = new File(s+"/???/item");  
         f.mkdirs();  
         ftpDownload("ftp://user@portalftp.?????.com/rooms.txt", f);  
    }  
    catch(Exception e)  
    {  
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download error: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
         toast.show();  
    }  

    ftpDisconnect();  
}  

public boolean ftpDownload(String srcFilePath, File desFilePath)  
{  
    boolean status = false;  
    try {  
        FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(desFilePath);  

        status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(srcFilePath, desFileStream);  
        desFileStream.close();  
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
        toast.show();  

        return status;  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download error"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
        toast.show();  
    }  

    return status;  
}  

 public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,  
        String password, int port)  
{  
    try{  
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();  
        // connecting to the host  

            mFTPClient.connect(host, port);  


        // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success  
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {  
            // login using username & password  
            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);  

            /* Set File Transfer Mode 
             * 
             * To avoid corruption issue you must specified a correct 
             * transfer mode, such as ASCII_FILE_TYPE, BINARY_FILE_TYPE, 
             * EBCDIC_FILE_TYPE .etc. Here, I use BINARY_FILE_TYPE 
             * for transferring text, image, and compressed files. 
             */  

            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);  
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();  

            return status;  
        }  
    } catch(Exception e) {  
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());  
    }  
    return false;  
 }  
}
```

Comment: We need a stack trace... tell us which line is erroring out.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` ... first: you are doing network related stuff on main thread ...

Comment: `Log.e` throws an exception if passed message is null. Make sure `e.getMessage()` is not null

Comment: maybe not directly related but : ftpDownload("ftp://user@portalftp.?????.com/rooms.txt", f);  
don't EVER do this in an activity main thread. Network calls must be done in a secondary thread (an easy way to do this is an AsyncTask) or they will block the UI (and the app will force close in recent versions of Android).

Comment: ... next `ftpConnect` return boolean ... but you never check if it is true or false ... i'm pretty sure that you are getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in `ftpConnect` and then it returns `false` but you still executing code like if there was no error at all

Comment: don't toast your exception. e.printStacktrace() instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
Log.e("ERROR", String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
```

That way, in case the message is null, you will get an output of "ERROR" , "null".

Also, you would be wise to listen to the people who suggest that you do your network related stuff on the main thread.